# How do I programmatically change a user's password as an admin using Grails Spring Security?

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-2.0

I need to be able to change a user's password as an admin user, sort of like a manual **password reset** feature that can be performed over the phone. How would I do this using the Grails Spring Security plugin? I tried looking for documentation on how this can be accomplished but didn't come up with anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@AA's answer is technically correct, but over-generic because the plugin has to be configuration-based. The real code would be a lot more compact since you can hard-code the class and field names. Also since you only asked to update the password, the role updates at the end aren't relevant.

If your user class name is `User` then use this action to display the user information:

```
def editUserPassword() {
   [user: User.get(params.userId)]
}
```

and configure the form in the GSP (it'd be similar to the generated `edit.gsp`) to post to this action:

```
def updateUserPassword() {
   def user = User.get(params.userId)
   user.password = params.newPassword
   if (!user.save())
      render view: 'editUserPassword', model: [user: user]
      return
   }

   // redirect to the 'success' page or render the user with [user: user]
}
```

Change `userId` and `newPassword` to whatever parameter names you're actually using

Comment: Cool, I just tried setting the password directly and it worked! I didn't realize Spring Security ties into GORM to automatically hash the password when you set the field. I thought I had to manually encrypt the password somehow.

Comment: That's new as of 1.2, it's optional but a good idea. The generated user class has the code, and you're free to remove it and encode the password however you like.

Answer (score 1):

You can use spring-security-ui plugin or you can see its [source code](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-ui/blob/master/grails-app/controllers/grails/plugins/springsecurity/ui/UserController.groovy) and learn how:

```
def update = {
    String passwordFieldName = SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig.userLookup.passwordPropertyName

    def user = findById()
    if (!user) return
    if (!versionCheck('user.label', 'User', user, [user: user])) {
        return
    }

    def oldPassword = user."$passwordFieldName"
    user.properties = params
    if (params.password && !params.password.equals(oldPassword)) {
        String salt = saltSource instanceof NullSaltSource ? null : params.username
        user."$passwordFieldName" = springSecurityUiService.encodePassword(params.password, salt)
    }

    if (!user.save(flush: true)) {
        render view: 'edit', model: buildUserModel(user)
        return
    }

    String usernameFieldName = SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig.userLookup.usernamePropertyName

    lookupUserRoleClass().removeAll user
    addRoles user
    userCache.removeUserFromCache user[usernameFieldName]
    flash.message = "${message(code: 'default.updated.message', args: [message(code: 'user.label', default: 'User'), user.id])}"
    redirect action: edit, id: user.id
}
```